# Knockout - How to set Observable Property to JSON REsult from asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

The MVC application returns a JSON REsult which contains a JSON object. For knockout 2 way binding to work it requires ko.observable("value").

Is there a way we can set two way binding to the JSON Object returned from MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can manually loop through your structure and create appropriate observables, you will probably want to look at the mapping plugin described here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html